# How to remove the 0 Division error on numpy arrays by list concatenation?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to alter RGB channels of an image from a numpy array.
Shown below is my code, and later the one I used to debug the error.

img is my image as read from open-cv 
I extracted the channels BGR to 3 numpy arrays, and red one is shown below.
Then I tried to map the 0-255 HEX to range 400nm - 700nm then to the respective frequencies 
I want to avoid the zero division error and find the maximum and minimum values of these arrays later. All the fixes I tried generates another error :(.

> yRed = img[:, :, 2]
>
> redFrequencies = np.array([speed_of_light/ ((300 * pow(10, -9) * yRed[i])/255) if ((300 * pow(10, -9) *                  yRed[i])/255).all() != 0 else np.array([1.0]) for i in range(0,len(yRed))]) 
>  # Index 1121 generate a 0 division error

# DEBUGGER
if(((300 * pow(10, -9) * yRed[1120])/255).all() == 0):
     print ("0 Error: ", type(speed_of_light/ np.array([1.0])))

else:
     print(type(((300 * pow(10, -9) * yRed[1121])/255)))
     print(type(speed_of_light/ ((300 * pow(10, -9) * yRed[i])/255)))

I added the "if condition" in the list comprehension to avoid the **0 division error**. (Earlier it was else divide by 1.0). It generated a **Value error** and suggested to use .all()

With .all() added, the code gives a "**ValueError**" saying "setting an array element with a sequence. 
*"The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions."*
As I found this is due to having multiple data type in a numpy array I replaced the else condition as np.array([1.0]) in the list comprehension.
(I also tried dtype=object but it generate errors when finding the minimum and maximum of the arrays in the later code.)

Any help extend in this regard is highly appreciated. Thank you very much!

 I hope I made myself clear in this reagard :(

Comment: format the question so that it is readable: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)